# Bounds on $b$ when solving $A^{-1}b = x$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm very inexperienced with linear algebra, so please bear with me.

For $Ax = b$:

I'm trying to solve for vector, $x$, given $n\times n$ matrix, $A$, and given $b$, where $y\le b\le z$. By bounds on $b$, I mean that the entries of $b$ are filled with parameters, each with their own set of bounds.

So, how do I calculate $x$ with the bounds around $b$? I've read through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and triangle nequality, but still not sure what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that $||y||\leq ||b||\leq ||z||$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! If $A$ is an invertible matrix, the solution is always $x=A^{-1}b$. It has nothing to do with whatever bounds on $\| b\|$.

Comment: @cmk. Sorry I shouldn't have said "given b". My overall objective is to calibrate a model with parameters in vector b using a linear transfer function. The model parameters, in vector b, can vary between lower & upper bounds, which are different for each parameter. I need to calibrate the linear transfer function parameters, in vector x, so that all combinations of Ax are within the bounds of b. Again, I'm new to linear algebra so sorry if I'm not explaining this well.

Comment: @Bernard. Please see my comment to cmk above. In regards to you, I have found solutions to x=A^−1b, but using different combinations of x values results in b values that are out of the upper or lower bounds of b.

Comment: Having bounds on $b$ doesn't make sense as you need $b$ to solve for $x$

Comment: you can put bounds on how accurate your answer will be for $x$ given $b$ however it depends on the way you solve for it.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand correctly, you want to characterize
$$\{A^{-1}\mathbf{b}\ \vert\ y_i \leq b_i \leq z_i\};$$
in other words you don't have an exact right-hand side $\mathbf{b}$, but you know that is lies within some high-dimensional rectangular box, and want to know what all possible solutions $\mathbf{x}$ are so that $A\mathbf{x}$ lies within the box.

I'm assuming that $A$ is nonsingular, in which case you know that that since $A^{-1}$ is linear, it maps planes to planes and therefore maps your box to a parallelepiped. You can also easily compute the half-space inequalities that define your parallelepiped: for example let's look at one of your box constraints,
$$A\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{e}_i \geq y_i$$
where $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the Euclidean basis vector. You can rewrite this inequality as a condition on $\mathbf{x}$:
$$\mathbf{x} \cdot A^T\mathbf{e}_i \geq y_i,$$
where of course $A^T\mathbf{e}_i$ is the $i$th row of your matrix. The preimage of your box is thus
$$\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \vert\ y_i \leq \mathbf{x}\cdot A^T\mathbf{e}_i \leq z_i\}.$$

What you do next, knowing the planes that bound $\mathbf{x}$, will depend on your application.

Comment: Thank you @user7530, but I've been trying to make this work all day and can't get it. Can you give me a simple example solution. Say A = ([1,2],[3,4]), and 1<= b <= 4.  Sorry if this is super basic, but never done linear algebra before.